# on click fires outside of hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a dynamic delete link that as such:

```
   <a id=\"removeAtt__" + i + "\" class=\"remove_button\" style=\"color:#aaa;\"><i class=\"fa fa-times-circle\"></i>&nbsp; remove</a>
```

I am using the following code once the link is clicked:

```
    $(document).on("click", $('[id*=removeAtt__]'), function () {            
        var id = event.target.id;
        var n = id.lastIndexOf('__');
        var result = id.substring(n + 2);
        $('#othAtt__' + result).remove();
    });
```

What I am finding is that even when I click outside of the hyperlink at times, it fires the delete. Is there a better way to do this so it fires on click of the hyperlink all the time.

Comment: With event delegation, the second parameter should be a *string*, not a jQuery collection, see [docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a selector, like

```
$(document).on("click", '.remove-button', function () {            
        var id = this.id;
        var n = id.lastIndexOf('__');
        var result = id.substring(n + 2);
        $('#othAtt__' + result).remove();
    });
```

And oldschool solution is to define a `function` to be executed when the button is clicked and call it in the `onclick` attribute of the tag.

Answer (score 0):

You're selector is not correct so it's actually executing on `$(document)`. This is my preference on writing jQuery selectors:

```
$('[id*=removeAtt__]').on("click", function () {            
  var id = $(this).attr('id);
  var n = id.lastIndexOf('__');
  var result = id.substring(n + 2);
  $('#othAtt__' + result).remove();
});
```

The reason is if my selector is off I don't get a false sense that code is actually working.